# Can Gradle task dependencies be set up to exclude a task?

Tags: gradle

We have in our build a lifecycle task which is supposed to run everything to do a quick check of the code. It looks like this:

```
  task minimalBuild(dependsOn: [jar, testJar, javadoc])
```

Someone said it should also run checks, which seems reasonable, except that if I depend on `check` itself, `check` depends on `test`, so all the tests will be run and it's no longer a quick build.

I could manually list the individual checks of course, and that is my best idea right now, but every time someone installs a new checking tool, they will have to update this list, and they might not know they have to.

Is there a way to do this programmatically at least? Can I make `minimalBuild` depend on "everything `check` depends on except for `test`"?

Answer (score 2):

You can onfigure it via `taskGraph`, like so:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(minimalBuild)) {
        tasks.withType(Test){
            enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration should be added to root of the script. It waits untill the execution graph is ready (it contains all the task, which should be really executed), after that it checks, whether `minimalBuild` task will be executed and if yes, then it disables all the tasks wit Test type.

Comment: What happens with this example if there is another task which does depend on test and I happen to have minimalBuild somewhere in the graph as well? I'd expect test to run in that situation.

Comment: There are 2 possible solutions: do not make any tasks depending on `minimalBuild`, if it needs to run tests, or make an `if`-expression checking for that there are no such a task within the graph. Unfortunately, if you create a task, whic disableas test then it's expected, that test won't be executed. If you have to run some special minimal build with tests, just create a separate task, which'll do the same, but do not disable tests